# Como alterar dois campos em JS

Tags: javascript, html

Entao, nao entendo muito de js, e meu problema é o seguinte: eu tenho uma lista de produtos no meu carrinho que mostra a quantidade, desconto, total unitario e subtotal. O js precisaria alterar o campo de quantidade e multiplicar pelo preço unitario, alterando automaticamente o subtotal. Da mesma forma que o campo desconto ao ser alterado ele deve acrescentar o desconto no preço do produto de acordo com sua quantidade e alterar tambem o subtotal.
Eu nao consigo alterar  o campo quantidade e desconto de formas independentes e dando resultado de no subtotal.

carrinho

```
<div class="div-venda3 carrinho">
    <h1 class="page-header carrinho_interno"> Carrinho </h1>   
    <br />
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="carrinhoth"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('ID'); ?></th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Nome'); ?></th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Quantidade'); ?></th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Desconto'); ?></th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Preço Uni.'); ?></th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Total'); ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho']))
            {
                $carrinho = $_SESSION['carrinho'];
                for ($i=0; $i < count($carrinho) ; $i++) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $carrinho[$i]['id']; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="<?= $carrinho[$i]['id']; ?>">
                        <td class="td-venda"><?= $carrinho[$i]['nome']; ?></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="nome[]" value="<?= $carrinho[$i]['nome']; ?>">
                        <td><input style="width: 30%;" type="number"  name="quantidade[]" class="quant" value="<?= $carrinho[$i]['quantidade']; ?>" min="1" max="<?= $carrinho[$i]['quantidade']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input style="width: 30%;" type="number"  name="desconto[]" class="desconto" value="">%</td>
                        <td>R$ <span class="preco_uni"><?= $carrinho[$i]['preco']; ?></span></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="preco[]" value="<?= $carrinho[$i]['preco']; ?>">
                        <td>R$ <span class="total_unitario">00.00</span></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="total_unitario">
                        <td><a href="?deletar=<?php echo $carrinho[$i]['id']; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">x</button></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                } 
            }?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

js

```
$(".desconto").on("input", function(){
    desconto = $(this).val();
    $(".quant").each(function(){
        quantidade = parseFloat($(this).val());
        precounitario = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find(".preco_uni").text());
        desconto = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find(".desconto").val());
        totalProd = (quantidade * precounitario);
        totalDesconto = (desconto * totalProd)/100;
        totalVenda = parseFloat(totalDesconto) + parseFloat(totalProd);
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_unitario").text((totalVenda).toFixed(2));
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_unitario").val((totalVenda).toFixed(2));

    });
     $(".quant").change(function(){
        quantidade = parseFloat($(this).val());
        precounitario = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find(".preco_uni").text());
        desconto = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find(".desconto").val());
        totalProd = (quantidade * precounitario);
        totalDesconto = (desconto * totalProd)/100;
        totalVenda = parseFloat(totalDesconto) + parseFloat(totalProd);
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_unitario").text((totalVenda).toFixed(2));
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".total_unitario").val((totalVenda).toFixed(2));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está fazendo errado, colocando um evento dentro de outro. Está colocando eventos `change` dentro do evento `input`, isso vai gerar conflito.

Pode fazer de uma forma muito mais simples, usando apenas um evento nos campos de desconto e quantidade de uma só vez, e buscar os elementos da linha alterada e realizar o cálculo.

Veja abaixo como é mais simples fazer isso:

```js
$(".quant, .desconto").on("input", function(){
   
   var linha = $(this).closest("tr"); // busca a linha o elemento alterado
   var subtotal_txt = linha.find(".total_unitario").eq(0); // busca a span do total
   var subtotal_val = linha.find(".total_unitario").eq(1); // busca o hidden do total

   var quant = linha.find(".quant").val() || 0; // busca a quantidade
   var desconto = linha.find(".desconto").val() || 0; // busca o desconto
   var preco = parseFloat(linha.find("[name='preco[]']").val()) || 0; // busca o preço

   var subtt = (quant*preco) - ((desconto/100)*(quant*preco)); // faz o cálculo
   subtt = subtt.toFixed(2); // aplica o toFixed
   
   subtotal_txt.text(subtt); // coloca o resultado na span
   subtotal_val.val(subtt); // coloca o resultado no input
});
```

```css
.table{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-venda3 carrinho">
    <h1 class="page-header carrinho_interno"> Carrinho </h1>   
    <br />
        <table class="table" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="carrinhoth">ID</th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth">Nome</th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth">Qtde</th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth">Desconto</th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth">Unit.</th>
                    <th class="carrinhoth">Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="1">
                     <td class="td-venda">Produto 1</td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="nome[]" value="Produto1">
                     <td><input style="width: 30%;" type="number"  name="quantidade[]" class="quant" value="2" min="1" max="10"></td>
                     <td><input style="width: 30%;" type="number"  name="desconto[]" class="desconto" value="">%</td>
                     <td>R$ <span class="preco_uni">3.00</span></td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="preco[]" value="3.00">
                     <td>R$ <span class="total_unitario">00.00</span></td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="total_unitario">
                     <td><a href="?deletar=1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">x</button></a></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>2</td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value="2">
                     <td class="td-venda">Produto 2</td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="nome[]" value="Produto2">
                     <td><input style="width: 30%;" type="number"  name="quantidade[]" class="quant" value="3" min="1" max="10"></td>
                     <td><input style="width: 30%;" type="number"  name="desconto[]" class="desconto" value="">%</td>
                     <td>R$ <span class="preco_uni">5.00</span></td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="preco[]" value="5.00">
                     <td>R$ <span class="total_unitario">00.00</span></td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="total[]" class="total_unitario">
                     <td><a href="?deletar=1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">x</button></a></td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa meu deus, obrigada e desculpa pela minha burrice, muito mais facil assim tambem. Obrigada!